# Error while running Dedoop Application : 500 call to server failed check the server log for the details

Tags: hadoop

I have installed the dedoop application on the hadoop server as per the instructions given at http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/howto_dedoop.  Now I am trying to run the application on the sample file which I have uploaded into HDFS system and see the output but while storing the output it is throwsing this error " 500 call to server failed check the server log for the details ".

The same error is thrown while I tried to create directory using application. The application can be seen here : http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/dedoop_slideshow/dedoop_slideshow.html